# Qt Base Class Function Definitions

Tags: c++, qt, class, inheritance, linker

I'm working on building a template library in a project that uses Qt5 using gcc 4.8.5, with the goal of sending and receiving types that share no inheritance hierarchy. One possible solution I came up with was that a base class can trivially define the signals and slots and the derived classes can provide the implementation, which works. Now, in the interest of compile-time optimization as well as run-time performance, what happens if I have hundreds of these methods in the base classes?

Another valid question I haven't been able to find seems to be what happens during compilation when two derived classes inherit the same object. Take the following example below:

```
class A{}

class B : A{}

class C : A{}
```

Are there any compile-time benefits to this structure? Additionally, Qt does not create a moc for a class unless it defines a signal or slot, so would having

```
class A {
    void slot_1();
    //...
    void slot_100();
}
```

Grind compilation to a halt, and does this have any runtime overhead? I know that  underneath a Qt slot is just a function, such that only one function is created in memory. Additionally, I know that the derived class must link the moc_a.o file, but I'm not quite sure to what extent the linker is able to optimize.

Note: I know this violates SRP and OCP, but the biggest concerns and impediments I have are listed above. I'm willing to look into alternate examples and work-arounds as long as they aren't needlessly complicated and compile-time friendly. ISP is also out the door, I'm simply not doing that much multiple inheritance.

Comment: Not clear to me, you start with speaking of *no inheritance hierarchy* and then about deriving QObject to implement signal/slots. Virtual functions have a little runtime overhead yes but unless you are working on embedded cheap system, it is most of the time negligible. What's your exact question ?

Comment: i’ll post an update later but my question is if i added all possible signals and slots to a base class, where each derived template class only uses one signal, is my compiler going to handle it or freak out when during compiling/linking. I figured out how to do it by castin functions though so

Comment: @jfhcs Why even ask? You can programmatically generate the `.h` file and a bunch of template instantiations and compile it and see. But there's zero reason to do that. Thanks to Qt Quick, Qt fully supports online generation of both signals and slots.

Answer (score 1):

This is an XY problem: you're asking about a solution, but what is the actual problem you're trying to solve? What are those classes representing? What do you mean by "sending and receiving types"? As for not sharing the inheritance hierarchy, there are simple ways around it: a common interface can be provided by a commonly implemented method, and you can introspect that method if you add `Q_GADGET` or `Q_OBJECT` to the classes - assuming that they are not `QObject`s already. If do you use `QObject`, then you can invoke methods programmatically via `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`, or via `QMetaMethod::invokeOnGadget` on `Q_GADGET` types, and there's no need indeed for any common interface other than `QObject` itself.

Example:

```
#include <QtCore>

class Class1 {
  Q_GADGET
public:
  Q_INVOKABLE void foo() { qDebug() << "Class1::foo"; }
};

class Class2 : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Q_SLOT void foo() { qDebug() << "Class2::foo"; }
};

class Class3 : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Q_SLOT void bar() { qDebug() << "Class3::bar"; }
};

template <class C> QMetaMethod getMethod(const C& c, const char *signature) {
  auto const &mo = c.staticMetaObject;
  auto const nSignature = QMetaObject::normalizedSignature(signature);
  int index = mo.indexOfMethod(nSignature);
  if (index >= 0)
    return mo.method(index);
  return {};
}

int main() {
  Class1 c1;
  Class2 c2;
  Class3 c3;
  auto foo1 = getMethod(c1, "foo()");
  auto foo2 = getMethod(c2, "foo()");
  auto bar3 = getMethod(c3, "bar()");
  foo1.invokeOnGadget(&c1);
  foo2.invoke(&c2);
  bar3.invoke(&c3);  
}
#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Would you believe me if I said I was able to implement signals in templates by casting the parameter of the function to the template type in a reinterpret_cast of the function pointer in the connect call? Without object slicing even if pass by value ( I know Qt makes copies if it’s not a const& but shhh)

Comment: @jfhcs I have no idea what you mean "signals in templates". If you're asking about whether signals can be added to template types: of course they can be. But you're not telling us what you're after. Provide an example of the "template" library you're working on. What does it do?

Comment: I've found a way to add signals to template classes without having to declare them of each concrete type in a base class.

Comment: Of course. And you can do that really for any class, templated or not. That's because signals can be generated completely dynamically. That's what makes QML possible. That's also what makes PyQt possible. And really all other Qt-to-scripting-language bridges, too. See `private/qmetaobjectbuilder_p.h`.

Comment: You can also use [Verdigris](https://woboq.com/blog/verdigris-qt-without-moc.html) to do it at compile-time.